# Function with two switch cases will only log one string

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, blackjack

Im new to coding and javascript, atm im doing som tests in school.

I have this function with two different switch cases with strings which i want to add together and return. But it only returns one of the strings. If i use switch(card.value) on the first and switch(card.suit) on the second it only returns the first one. But if i take it away on the frist one:
switch(value) and switch(card.suit) it return string from the lower switch-case. Why is that? And how do i get it to return A♥? Here is the code. Sorry for my messy description.

```
const prettyCard = function (card) {
  let suit, value

  switch (card.value) {
    case 1:
      return 'A';
      break;
    case 10:
      return 'T';
      break;
    case 11:
      return 'J';
      break;
    case 12:
      return 'Q';
      break;
    case 13:
      return 'K';
      break;
    case 2:
      return '2';
      break;
    case 3:
      return '3';
      break;
    case 4:
      return '4';
      break;
    case 5:
      return '5';
      break;
    case 6:
      return '6';
      break;
    case 7:
      return '7';
      break;
    case 8:
      return '8';
      break;
    case 9:
      return '9';
      break;
  }

  switch (card.suit) {
    case 'HEARTS':
      return '♥';
      break;
    case 'SPADES':
      return '♠';
      break;
    case 'DIAMONDS':
      return '♦';
      break;
    case 'CLUBS':
      return '♣';
      break;
  }
  return value + suit
}
console.log(prettyCard({ suit: 'HEARTS', value: 1 }))
```

Comment: you should be assigning the variables `value` and `suit`, not returning from the switch cases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fix suggested in comments, the code can shrink considerably by looking-up suits and values in an object, rather than a long switch.

```js
const prettyCard = card => {
  const values = { 1: 'A', 11: 'J', 12: 'Q', 13: 'K' }
  const suits  = { 'HEARTS': '♥', 'SPADES': '♠', 'DIAMONDS': '♦', 'CLUBS': '♣' };

  const suit = suits[card.suit];
  const value = card.value > 1 && card.value < 11 ? `${card.value}` : values[card.value];
  return { suit, value };
}

console.log(prettyCard({ value: 12, suit: 'HEARTS' }))
```